# Obtain Site Name in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

If we run `proc setinit` in SAS we can obtain the Site Name and the Site Number.

The Site Number can be easily extracted using `&syssite`.  Other than redirecting & parsing log output, is there a way to programmatically obtain the Site *Name*?

I've checked `_automatic_` variables, `sashelp` datasets, and `proc registry` output to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and didn't involve setting up the metadata server:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.temp 
        DATAFILE= "D:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\core\sasinst\setinit.sss" 
        DBMS=DLM REPLACE;
        DELIMITER='3D'x; 
        GETNAMES=NO;
        DATAROW=1; 
RUN;

proc sql noprint;
     select var2 into: name
     from temp
     where var1 = 'SITEINFO NAME';
quit;

%put &name;
```

Comment: this didn't work for me - I tried: `"%sysget(SASHOME)/SASFoundation/&sysver/core/sasinst/setinit.sss"` which resolved to `/pub/sas/SASFoundation/9.4/core/sasinst/setinit.sss` and I got "file does not exist" (which it didn't).  I tried searching for `setinit.sss` and it's not on my system, but searching for `setinit*` produced a number of files.  This doesn't seem like a robust way to obtain the settings (ie, it would work on any SAS site) but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: If there was a robust way to find that setinit file without having to use metadata that would definitely be preferable, I agree..

Comment: do you think the sid file is on every sas site?  The information is contained in there too.

Comment: I suspect you are reading a file that your administrator saved to apply the setinits.  There probably isn't a consistent location or name for that file, if it even exists.

Comment: @ dcr - I don't know but again, I don't think SAS will necessarily know where it has been saved.  @tom - I think you're right

Answer (score 3):

Here is code to parse it from the output of `PROC SETINIT`.

```
filename out temp;
proc printto log=out; run;
proc setinit; run;
proc printto log=log; run;
data sitename;
  infile out;
  input @'Site name:' @;
  length sitename $200;
  sitename=scan(_infile_,2,"'");
  put sitename=;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: indeed, without metadata, it seems that log redirect is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

With pointers from Chris Blake and FriedEgg, I ended up with this solution:

```
data _null_;
  length StoredText $2000 sitename $200;
  rc=metadata_getattr("omsobj:TextStore?@Name='Setinit text'"
    , "StoredText", StoredText);
  storedtext=subpad(storedtext,index(storedtext,'SITEINFO NAME=')+15);
  sitename=substr(storedtext,1,index(storedtext,"'")-1);
  put sitename=;
run;
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you aren't running metadata manager.  If you are just running SAS it will pop-up a window to log into a metadata server.

Comment: For my use case this was sufficient, appreciate that not everyone has metadata though

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using SAS in UNIX environment because the path you wrote, then this document will helps.
[Contents of the !SASROOT Directory - SAS® 9.4 Companion for UNIX Environments, Sixth Edition](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostunx&docsetTarget=n0kz50mbvjknxfn1hscm84o10ac8.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Then the answer from @SCR comes in handy. As the document said

> The !SASROOT directory contains the files required to use SAS 9.4.

and

> If all available SAS products are installed on your system, the !SASROOT directory contains the files and directories that are listed in the following tables:

a file named "setinit.sas" is listed in the table in that link.
By the Way, I tried the answer from @SCR on my Windows machine, it works. Please also mind the path is `"%sysget(SASROOT)\core\sasinst\setinit.sss"`.

Comment: Hi @whymath - thanks for the answer, however that directory does not exist in our (unix, you are correct) system.  The doc link was helpful, and it correctly states that a `setinit.sas` file exists in !SASROOT (it does), however - that file is empty.